# Current python for loop not efficent

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I have the following working code

```
import numpy as np
r = np.loadtxt('CoordUnwrapped/ParticleCoordU.5000',skiprows=9,usecols = (4,5,6))
rcom = np.loadtxt('hexaCOM/COMA/COMA.5000',skiprows=10,usecols = (4,5,6))
N = 50 

Sx1= []
Sx2 = []
Sx3 = []
for i in range(0,N):
    S_data_1 = (r[i,0]-rcom[0,0])**2)
    S_data_2 = (r[i+N,0]-rcom[1,0])**2)
    S_data_3 = (r[i+2*N,0]-rcom[2,0])**2)
    Sx1.append(S_data_1)
    Sx2.append(S_data_2)
    Sx3.append(S_data_3)

data = np.array([Sx1,Sx2,Sx3])

x = np.average(data, axis=0)
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I am looking to obtain 400 Sx vectors and with this format it is not really feasible. Just to be clear this is a snapshot of what I am looking to get at the end:

```
N = 50 

Sx1= []
Sx2 = []
Sx3 = []
.
.
.
Sx400 = []

for i in range(0,N):
    S_data_1 = (r[i,0]-rcom[0,0])**2)
    S_data_2 = (r[i+N,0]-rcom[1,0])**2)
    S_data_3 = (r[i+2*N,0]-rcom[2,0])**2)
    .
    .
    .
    S_data_400 = (r[i+399*N,0]-rcom[399,0]**2)
    Sx1.append(S_data_1)
    Sx2.append(S_data_2)
    Sx3.append(S_data_3)

data = np.array([Sx1,Sx2,Sx3,...,Sx400])

x = np.average(data, axis=0)
```

As you can see this approach is too time consuming and not efficient at all. Any suggestions would be great. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to read some Python books or tutorials. Solving this issue was taught to my class in the first couple of lessons of formal (high school) education.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any need to name all your Sx variables and copy+paste the code to build each one; just build them in another loop.  You can do both loops as list comprehensions very concisely:

```
data = np.array([
    [(r[i+s*N, 0] - rcom[s, 0])**2 for i in range(N)]    
    for s in range(400)
])
```